# Contactless integration of Z-Wave capability into blinds and SomFy-remote system

Tags: smart-home

I want to control a couple of Garber blinds via my Z-Wave network. I already have a `SomFy` remote (looks the same/similar model as the picture in the link) to control the blinds, which a local dealer installed.
[image]

Since I didn't install the blinds by myself, and am afraid to break the warranty, I prefer a solution that doesn't require physical contact to the blinds if possible. Ideally I want something that can communicate with `Z-Wave`, and can also wirelessly bridge with the blinds. Something that tranceives and speaks both [SomFy RTS (somfy.co.uk)](https://www.somfy.co.uk/help-me-choose/rts-products) and Z-Wave's protocol.

"What component do I need" may be more appropriate thing to ask fearing [xy problem (xyproblem.info)](https://xyproblem.info/). However, that might be taken as asking about a product recommendation, which may violate this forum's rule. So instead, my question is rather solution-specific:

**Question.** Does this product work for my purpose? [Z-Wave to RTS Plug-in Wall Module (ZRTSI) (somfysystems.com)](https://www.somfysystems.com/en-us/products/1811265/z-wave-to-rts-plug-in-wall-module-zrtsi-16-channel)

My guess is yes, as long as I know how to connect this new item to my blinds (which I don't know yet. Will have to ask the dealer who installed the blinds and the remote). Required compatibility of this item is RTS. The fact that the our blinds can be controlled by an aforementioned remote, which must be `RTS` capable, I think our blinds are RTC compatible.

Note I tried to contact [their customer support (somfysystems.com)](https://www.somfysystems.com/en-us/discover-somfy/contact-us/general-inquiries), but after filling up the question fields the website didn't let me press "submit" button :/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a wifi  ir/rf universal remote control. An affordable option is tuya systems. They Support RF (433MHz fixed code, not rolling code) controlled devices so i believe it will suit the blinds.

Comment: +1 for alternative, I may try. I just keep this question open to wait for more direct answers.